# Get Id for updating values by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple page, that shows answers of a question. 
When a user click on "Useful" or "Useless" button , i want to get that answer's Id and update useful or useless field in DB using jQuery. My problem is how can i get each AnswerId using jQuery?

Here is AnswerModel:

```
   public class Answer
   {
       public int AnswerId { get; set; }

       [Required]
       [StringLength(500)]
       public string Reply { get; set; }

       public int Useful { get; set; }

       public int Useless { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is AnswerController:

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return(await db.Answers.toListAsync());
    }

    public async Task<JsonResult> Helpful(int? ansId, int? useful, int? uselees)
    {
        Answer model = await db.Answers.FindAsync(ansId);
        if (model != null)
        {
            model.Useful  = model.Useful + (int)useful;
            model.Useless = model.Useless + (int)useless;
            db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Json(new { Success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new { Success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is Index View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<project.Models.Answer>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Reply: @item.Reply
            </td>                
            <th>
                <input type="button" id="usfBtn" value="Useful" />
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="button" id="uslBtn" value="Useless" />
            </th>
        </tr>
        </table>
    }
```

And here is the script:

```
    $(function() {
               $("#usfBtn").click(function () {        
                    Usf(Alarm);
                 });
               $("#uslBtn").click(function () {
                   Usl(Alarm);
                });
                function Usf(callback) {
                $.ajax(
                {
                      type: "Get",
                      url: "/Answer/Helpful",
                      data: {
                              useful: 1,
                              useless: 0,
                            },
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (result) {
                      callback(result);
                  }
               });
              }
              function Usl(callback) {
                 $.ajax(
                 {
                     type: "Get",
                     url: "/Answer/Helpful",
                     data: {
                            useful: 0,
                            useless: 1,
                     },
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (result) {
                         callback(result);
                     }
               });
            }
            function Alarm(arg) {
                 if (arg.Success) {
                        window.location.href = window.location.pathname;
                 }
            }
  });
```

My question is how can i get each Answer's Id while i have just one button Id for all of them ("usfBtn" or "uslBtn")?

Comment: You can use class instead `.usfBtn` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the answer id the data attribute of the button.

```
<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td>
            Reply: @item.Reply
        </td>                
        <th>
            <input type="button" data-aid="@item.Id" class="u" 
                        data-mode="useful"  value="Useful" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="button" data-aid="@item.Id" class="u" 
                       data-mode="useless" value="Useless" />
        </th>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Now read the data attribute values and send it to the server

```
$(function(){

  $("input.u").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var s= { ansId : $(this).data("aid"), useful :0, useless:0 };
     if($(this).data("mode")=="useful")
     {
       s.useful = 1;
     }
     else if($(this).data("mode")=="useless")
     {
       s.useless = 1;
     }
     //post this object now
     $.post("/Answer/Helpful",s,function(res){
        //do something with response.
     });

  });

});
```

Comment: when i trace $.post("/Ans.....") in debug mode , i get always  ansId = null

Comment: Did you set the data attribute for `aid` in the button ?

Comment: Sorry ! There was a small error. I was not properly reading the data attribute value for answer id. Fixed now. Take a look at the updated answer.  [Here](http://jsbin.com/hamumaquqo/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample.

Comment: yes :     <input type="button" data-aid="@item.AnswerId" class="use"
                       data-mode="useful"value="Useful" />